# Upgrade ElasticSearch from 2 to 7.6

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new in elasticsearch. I want To upgrade Elasticsearch from 2 to 7. IS that required to reindex before into the version 5 ?

Can Some One please guide me to do this upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it is not required.

You can simply create a new cluster with version ***7.x.x*** and execute a [`Reindex from Remote`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/reindex-upgrade-remote.html) which is basically moving the documents from ES version ***2.x*** to version ***7.x***. Make sure that you understand the history of changes occurred w.r.t mappings.

The aforementioned link contains sequence of steps as what all you have to take into consideration.

However if you are stuck with no additional hardware and have to do it in place, in that case, you may have to follow long path i.e. upgrade from ***[Elasticsearch 2.x to 5.6](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/reindex-upgrade.html)*** via [`reindex in place`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.6/reindex-upgrade.html#reindex-upgrade-inplace) and then perform [`rolling upgrades`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-upgrade.html) to latest version of ES.

Answer (score 0):

I am not even sure that you can do a direct upgrade. I'd setup some sort of custom process to bring data from v2 into v7.x.